Counterintuitive INVALID_ARGUMENT error in request to Google's KMS API
I am writing a Typescript, Node.js backend that interacts with Google's KMS API.
Drawing from the samples, I want to expose a function that creates an asymmetric RSA key for signing. My attempt looks like this, building a request object that conforms to Google's API documentation
    export const createRSAKey = async (parentKeyRingName: string, cryptoKeyId: string) => {
    // Instantiates a client
    const kmsClient = new KeyManagementServiceClient();

    async function callCreateCryptoKey() {
        // Construct request
        const request = {
            parent: parentKeyRingName,
            cryptoKeyId,
            cryptoKey: {
                purpose: google.cloud.kms.v1.CryptoKey.CryptoKeyPurpose.ASYMMETRIC_SIGN,
                version_template: {
                    protection_level: google.cloud.kms.v1.ProtectionLevel.SOFTWARE,
                    algorithm: google.cloud.kms.v1.CryptoKeyVersion.CryptoKeyVersionAlgorithm.RSA_SIGN_PKCS1_4096_SHA256,
                },
            },
            skip_initial_version_creation: false,
        };

        console.log("Sending request", request);

        // Run request
        const response = await kmsClient.createCryptoKey(request);
        console.log(response);
    }
}

It seems to me that the request is well formed, in fact the object that is sent, after obscuring parent and key Ids, looks like.
Sending request {
  parent: '***',
  cryptoKeyId: '***',
  cryptoKey: {
    purpose: 5,
    version_template: { protection_level: 1, algorithm: 7 }
  },
  skip_initial_version_creation: false
}

And yet I run into the following error, complaining that the version_template.algorithm field is missing:
Error: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: Request field version_template.algorithm is required if purpose is not ENCRYPT_DECRYPT.
...
code: 3,
details: 'Request field version_template.algorithm is required if purpose is not ENCRYPT_DECRYPT.'
...

If I remove both purpose and version_template, then the API complains that purpose is required, which leads me to believe at least purpose is being interpreted correctly. Is version_template somehow wrong?

The error you are facing with the Google KMS API is due to the missing required fields that's the reason you are getting the INVALID_ ARGUMENT error.
As per this official doc:

Returns an error if called on a key whose purpose is not ENCRYPT_DECRYPT. You need to Update the version of a CryptoKey that
will be used in Encrypt.
Request object method variants only take one parameter, a request
object, which must be constructed before the call.

updateCryptoKeyPrimaryVersion(UpdateCryptoKeyPrimaryVersionRequest request)

"Flattened" method variants have converted the fields of the request
object into function parameters to enable multiple ways to call the
same method.

updateCryptoKeyPrimaryVersion(CryptoKeyName name, String cryptoKeyVersionId)
updateCryptoKeyPrimaryVersion(String name, String cryptoKeyVersionId)

Callable method variants take no parameters and return an immutable
API callable object, which can be used to initiate calls to the
service.

updateCryptoKeyPrimaryVersionCallable()


Since you are creating a Asymmetric key for signing you need to include the Version_template.alogirthm in your request
Refer to this github link for more information and Refer to this Google cloud KMS  document to update cryptoKeys.updatePrimaryVersion.

I am not following what you posted, I know that I need to pass the version_template.algorithm parameter in my request, but that's exactly what I am doing. Are you suggesting this is not the right way to do it?

The error you are facing  whose purpose is not ENCRYPT_DECRYPT is due to the  missing required fields. To resolve your issue you need to Update the version of a CryptoKey that will be used in Encrypt
